# Mass duplicate flagging of "What kernel version does ubuntu X ship with?"

Tags: discussion, duplicates

I propose that these questions:

- [Determine which kernel ships with which Ubuntu version](https://askubuntu.com/questions/743181/determine-which-kernel-ships-with-which-ubuntu-version?rq=1)
- [4.0.6 kernel in which ubuntu version?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/646084/4-0-6-kernel-in-which-ubuntu-version?rq=1)
- [what kernel version comes with ubuntu 10.04.1?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/10308/what-kernel-version-comes-with-ubuntu-10-04-1?rq=1)
- [What kernel version comes with 11.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/49546/what-kernel-version-comes-with-11-04?rq=1)
- [What kernel version does Ubuntu Server 10.04.3 LTS come with?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/65684/what-kernel-version-does-ubuntu-server-10-04-3-lts-come-with?rq=1)

Should be flagged as duplicates of this question: [List of Ubuntu Versions with Corresponding Linux Kernel Version](https://askubuntu.com/questions/517136/list-of-ubuntu-versions-with-corresponding-linux-kernel-version?rq=1)

The benefit this will have is that [new users asking similar questions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1184638/whats-the-default-kernel-version-comes-with-ubuntu-16-04-6) might be seeing the questions in "suggested duplicates" but ignoring them because it doesn't contain the answer to their version. When we close them as duplicates, the user will go to the  [List of Ubuntu Versions with Corresponding Linux Kernel Version](https://askubuntu.com/questions/517136/list-of-ubuntu-versions-with-corresponding-linux-kernel-version?rq=1) question instead and find their answer there.

I wanted to ask if this is appropriate to do and if a mod could do it in one go instead of me having to raise duplicate flags for all of them

Answer (score 11):

Questions that are actually of the simple form **which kernel does *major version* come with?** may, I think, be closed as duplicates without any meaningful loss.

However, questions like [Which Ubuntu version has the 4.0.6 kernel which supports L2TP VPN?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/646084/which-ubuntu-version-has-the-4-0-6-kernel-which-supports-l2tp-vpn) should not be closed as such, since their details provide the potential for (and perhaps require) material that would not be appropriate in answers to [List of Ubuntu Versions with Corresponding Linux Kernel Version](https://askubuntu.com/questions/517136/list-of-ubuntu-versions-with-corresponding-linux-kernel-version).

We can see immediately that [Determine which kernel ships with which Ubuntu version](https://askubuntu.com/questions/743181/determine-which-kernel-ships-with-which-ubuntu-version), which is in my opinion misleadingly titled, is not a duplicate of [List of Ubuntu Versions with Corresponding Linux Kernel Version](https://askubuntu.com/questions/517136/list-of-ubuntu-versions-with-corresponding-linux-kernel-versio) because the published list and its copies here do not document the point release kernels but only the initial release kernel. I actually don't know of anywhere this information is documented or where the information in [that question's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/743183/527764) comes from. In fact, that question would benefit from a new answer that actually does tell us *how* to determine in advance (that is, without installation) the kernel version of a point release, with some clarity on the difference between vanilla kernel versions and Ubuntu kernel versions... Closing it would be a really bad idea I think! But, if such an answer were posted (and, probably, the question re-titled), it may then be reasonable to close questions of the form **what kernel version does *point release* come with?** against [Determine which kernel ships with which Ubuntu version](https://askubuntu.com/questions/743181/determine-which-kernel-ships-with-which-ubuntu-version).